# Format String Rounding Bug

Tags: python, rounding, format-string

Is it a bug or expected behavior to have rounding behave differently depending on the number of visible decimal places?

Demo via Interactive Interpreter

```py
Python 3.8.10
>>> a = 1.555
>>> f'{a:.0f}'
'2'
>>> f'{a:.1f}'
'1.6'
>>> f'{a:.2f}'
'1.55'
>>> f'{a:.3f}'
'1.555'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One way to make it accurate is to use `Decimal`:**

But, you could see `Decimal(1.555)` will output next:

```
>>> Decimal(1.555)
Decimal('1.5549999999999999378275106209912337362766265869140625')
```

Above could explain why we get the `1.55`, as the 3rd number is 4.

To fix that, we should change `float` to `str` as `float` is not accurate.

```
C:\Windows\System32>python
Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> a = "1.555"
>>> float(Decimal(a).quantize(Decimal("0")))
2.0
>>> float(Decimal(a).quantize(Decimal("0.1")))
1.6
>>> float(Decimal(a).quantize(Decimal("0.01")))
1.56
>>> float(Decimal(a).quantize(Decimal("0.001")))
1.555
>>>
```

So, when you need accurate, consider to using `Decimal`.

Comment: `str(1.555)` is fairly pointless…?!

Comment: `float(Decimal(1.555).quantize(Decimal("0.01")))` will output `1.55` while `float(Decimal(str(1.555)).quantize(Decimal("0.01")))` will output `1.56`

Comment: Yeah, but then why not `'1.555'`? If you're suggesting that you can put any calculated float value through `str` to gain more accuracy or a different behaviour, then no: the accuracy is already lost the moment you have a float as such. Channeling that through `str` or `Decimal` or whatever just kind of randomises how and where exactly it gets rounded; it can't add any accuracy where there was none to begin with.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that. Despite of what the detail mechanism is, back to the more user level question, it could be "how I could let 1.555 be worked as usual rounding function does?", in that case, "1.555" and 1.555 are same to the question. As a user which use the software, they won't care the number is str or int, the software just try to understand their requirement. Yes, for str, we could use above method to realize their requirement, while for int, software change the format and let user do get the correct answer. So you suggest to directly use '1.555' as the input if I catch your idea?

Comment: *"As a user which use the software, they won't care"* — You as a developer need to care and understand. If you use floats—at any point in your program—you can forget about any specific expectations you have with regards to the *exact* value of that float. You'll get *some* value close to what you put in, but you can never expect any one particular value. If you *do* care about specific values, you need to keep your numbers as strings and do arithmetic with `Decimal` from start to finish.

Comment: aha, although I have reservations, as I think programmer should stand on the user's angle to think about things. (Or we could think `str(a)` as a adapter to trans user's requirement to program world). But, I'd like to admit your idea makes some sense here, I modify that to avoid such confuse... though...

Comment: Unfortunately as a programmer you're not in the position to not need to care. It's your job to bridge the divide between the user's expectations and the realities of the nitty gritty implementation details.

Answer (score 8):

`a` is actually slightly smaller than 1.555 due to imprecise representation of floating point values.

You can see this, for example, as follows:

```
f"{a:.40f}"
'1.5549999999999999378275106209912337362766'
```

Or,

```
f"{a:.64f}"
'1.5549999999999999378275106209912337362766265869140625000000000000'
```

Comment: ^ I got distracted before I could post an answer, but this is the correct answer. Other values that look like `1.x55` that end up slightly smaller than `1.x55` also format to two places as `1.x5`. E.g. `f"{1.755:.2f}"` -> `1.75`